# curl ssl certificate error with CAfile: none in windows

Tags: curl

I am using the curl command like below in windows cmd.

```
curl -v https://golang.org/dl/?mode=json
*   Trying 142.250.9.141:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to golang.org (142.250.9.141) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: C:\Users\XXXXXX
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

CAfile shows as none. But I already set User environment variables for the same.

```
CAfile=C:\Users\xxxxx\cacert.pem
```

The same it works when I try add --cafile in the curl command with the pem or cer file.

I added the cer and crt format but it's the same issue. I am using the curl version 7.68.0

```
curl -V
curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.68.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1d (Schannel) zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 WinIDN libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.40.0
Release-Date: 2020-01-08
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile MultiSSL NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI TLS-SRP brotli libz
```

Spent some time looking into the other relevant post but still struggle with same issue. Any inputs to include CAfile in windows 10 (cmd).

Comment: so you run the `curl` command from cmd line. Confirm that CAfile is really set by typing `echo %CAfile%` (`echo $CAfile` for linux). If empty, then on linux, try `set | grep -i cafile`. Maybe there is CA_file? Good l uck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CAfile shows as none. But I already set User environment variables for the same.
>
> ```
>  CAfile=C:\Users\xxxxx\cacert.pem
> ```
>
> The same it works when I try add --cafile in the curl command with the pem or cer file.

There is neither a `CAfile` environment variable nor a `--cafile` command line argument documented for curl. What is [documented instead](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--cacert):

> **--cacert**
>
> (TLS) Tells curl to use the specified certificate file to verify the
> peer. The file may contain multiple CA certificates. ...
>
> curl recognizes the environment variable named **'CURL_CA_BUNDLE'** if it
> is set, and uses the given path as a path to a CA cert bundle. This
> option overrides that variable.